# Is there a way to convert a list of li's in a ul into an array?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, html-lists

I am fetching some data and it comes back like this:

```
> denialReasonContent: {   denialReason: "<ul>\n <li>denial reason
> 1</li>\n <li>denial reason 2</li>\n</ul>" };
```

I'm trying to take this data of a ul element full of li's and covert to an array that would look like this

```
var denialReasons = [{denialReason: denial reason 1}, {denialReason: denial reason 2}];
```

What's the best approach to parse this data and convert to a new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure to get valid html string as a response this code can help

```js
let denialReasonContent =  { denialReason: `<ul>\n <li>denial reason 1</li>\n <li>denial reason 2</li>\n</ul>` };


 let div = document.createElement('div');

 div.innerHTML = denialReasonContent.denialReason


 let list = div.getElementsByTagName("li")


 let data = [];


for(let i=0; i<list.length;i++) {
  data.push({denialReason:list[i].innerText})
}

console.log(data)

// [{denialReason: denial reason 1}, {denialReason: denial reason 2}];
```

Comment: Awesome this is perfect thank you!